# Rails: Save a record in DB based on params in sign up url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mongoid

I'm using Rails 3, mongoid and devise.

Depending on what "plan" you choose to sign up with you get a different URL, for example: Plan 2 will get `http://example.com/users/sign_up?account_level=2`

`account_level` is a record in my users model to store what account level a user is.

How do I get the account_level with a value of 2, to save that number to the db when someone signs up using that link?

Comment: in the `sign_up` action, you should be able to access `params[:account_level]` which will contain `2`.  you can add this in the session if you plan to use it after the user successfully signs up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

Assuming you have `sign_up` method in `users_controller`:

```
def sign_up
  account_level = params[:account_level]  #or you can use `params[:account_level] directly
  #do your stuff
end
```